# Media queries for iPhone load css for iPhone 10 while iPhone is 8

Tags: css, iphone, media-queries, mobile-safari

I have a bunch of css media queries written for various iPhones however, the code is messed up. The iPhone load css for iPhone 10, while it is an iPhone, is 8. I think it has to do with the maximum screen size part overlapping each other. Any good solution to fix this? E.g. use extract screen sizes for the specific phones?

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover'>
    <style>
    body{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        background-color:green;
    }
    header{
        height:100vh;
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
    }
    .iphone6,
    .iphone6plus,
    .iphone10{
        display:none;
    }
    /* ----------- iPhone 6, 6S, 7 and 8 ----------- */
    /* Portrait */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 375px) 
      and (max-device-width: 667px)
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
      and (orientation: portrait) { 
        header{
            background-color:red;
            height:calc(100vh - 57px);
        }
        .iphone6,
        .iphone6plus,
        .iphone10{
            display:none;
        }
        .iphone6{
            display:block;
        }
    }
    /* Landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 375px) 
      and (max-device-width: 667px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
      and (orientation: landscape) { 
        header{
            background-color:blue;
            height:calc(100vh);
        }
        .iphone6,
        .iphone6plus,
        .iphone10{
            display:none;
        }
        .iphone6{
            display:block;
        }

    }
    /* ----------- iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+ ----------- */
    /* Portrait */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 414px) 
      and (max-device-width: 736px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
      and (orientation: portrait) { 
        header{
            background-color:pink;
            height:calc(100vh - 57px);
        }
        .iphone6,
        .iphone6plus,
        .iphone10{
            display:none;
        }
        .iphone6plus{
            display:block;
        }

    }
    /* Landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 414px) 
      and (max-device-width: 736px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
      and (orientation: landscape) { 
        header{
            background-color:orange;
            height:calc(100vh);
        }
        .iphone6,
        .iphone6plus,
        .iphone10{
            display:none;
        }
        .iphone6plus{
            display:block;
        }

    }

    /* ----------- iPhone X ----------- */
    /* Portrait */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 375px) 
      and (max-device-width: 812px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
      and (orientation: portrait) { 
        header{
            background-color:yellow;
            height:calc(100vh - 57px);
        }
        .iphone6,
        .iphone6plus,
        .iphone10{
            display:none;
        }
        .iphone10{
            display:block;
        }

    }

    /* Landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 375px) 
      and (max-device-width: 812px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
      and (orientation: landscape) { 
        header{
            background-color:olive;
            height:calc(100vh);
        }
        .iphone6,
        .iphone6plus,
        .iphone10{
            display:none;
        }
        .iphone10{
            display:block;
        }

    }


    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <header class="iphone6">
        iphone 6
    </header>
    <header class="iphone6plus">
        iphone 6 plus
    </header>
    <header class="iphone10">
        iphone 10
    </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely not the perfect solution but it works. I used a media query where the min-device-width and max-device-width are exactly that the device widths are, like this I could specifically target the iPhone X and adjust styles accordingly.

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 375px)
  and (min-device-height: 812px) 
  and (max-device-height: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
    header{
        background-color:yellow;
        height:calc(100vh - 57px);
    }
    .iphone6,
    .iphone6plus,
    .iphone10{
        display:none;
    }
    .iphone10{
        display:block;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pixel ratio(`device-pixel-ratio`) of iphone 8 and 8+ is `2` and `3`, IMO that is reason you are facing that issue.

To know more about `device-pixel-ratio`, & others info about devices, please check below  link https://www.mydevice.io/#compare-devices

```
/* iPhone 6+, 6s+, 7+, 8+ --------> 3 */
@media only screen .... (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) .... { }
```

and

```
/* iPhone 4, 5, 7, 6, 6s, and 8 --------> 2 */
@media only screen .... (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) .... { }
```

please update your css as per `device-pixel-ratio` and see if it works fine, hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, have a look at the source code I've posted above, I've got the -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio set correctly as you've suggested. Maybe I should add additional info specific to the device?